# Prestashop webservice PSWebServiceLibrary returned empty order details

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

To get a particular shop orders, I am using PSWebServiceLibrary.php from [LINK](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php) on prestashop 1.6.

This is my code

```
require_once 'PSWebServiceLibrary.php';
$opt['id'] = 1; // Looking for details for order 1 
$opt['resource'] = 'orders';

// Call
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('http://myprestashop_shop_url.com', '*****', true);
$xml = $webService->get($opt);

$resources = $xml->children()->children();

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($resources);
echo '</pre>';


RETURN HTTP BODY has returned all the values I am looking for as shown on pic1.
```

[image: pic1]

But $resources returned empty values as shown on pic2. [image: pic2]

**NOTE: In the Advance Parameters/Webservice I have enabled all including order_details and order_histories.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resources` is not empty, it contains SimpleXMLElement Objects. Try `echo $resources->id`.

Comment: Well it returned 1. So how to retrieve the order details values? Thanks again for the quick answer

Comment: @Lomse You can cast them to int or string like this: `$id = (int) $resources->id`

Comment: @yenshirak can you help me on this trouble : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483638/add-order-web-service/32484847#32484847 ? thanks in advance